# azure data factory get the largest file in several folders

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In an azure storage account I have a container with several folders (one for each month). In these folders there are several csv files. I need to get the largest file in each of these folders and copy them to another folder. I can do several steps in ADF but I'm not able to combine it all together.

I'm able to use the get metadata action to get all the foldernames in in the container. For each folder I would then need to use get metadata (child items) to get all the files in that specific folder. This can be done using a foreach step. Then I get stuck. As far as I can think of I somehow need to do another foreach on each outcome of the previous foreach step the get the size of all the individual files in that folder and the copy the largest file. I can do this when I only need to do it for one folder. I have no idea how to basically do a forech on an array of foldernames where each entry contains an array of filenames.

Hope this makes sense and hope someone know how this can be achieved. some crude visual below

Start:

-Folder A
--big file A
--small file A
-Folder B
--big file B
--small file B

Result:

-Folder C:
--big file A
--big file B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve your requirement by the below approach.

These are my files in two folders:

**FolderA:**

[image]

**FolderB:**

[image]

I followed the same approach as yours and I used dataset parameters for the sub folder name and file name in iterations.

In ADF nested Foreach activities are not supported. So, build the inner Foreach in another pipeline and call it inside the parent pipeline by passing the Child items of the folder in every iteration and the sub folder name.

In Child pipeline, create an array parameter for the child items(files) and a string parameter for the current subfolder. Then pass the values for those like below.

[image]

In Child pipeline,

- First initialize an integer variable with value of `0` i.e., dynamic content `@int('0')`.Also create another string variable for storing large filename.
- Then use Foreach and pass the array parameter which contains the Child items.
- Inside Foreach, use Get Meta data activity to get the file size(Use dataset parameters for subfolder and filename and pass current subfolder parameter, current file name`@item().name` respectively).
- Now, we will compare the variable and the size from Get meta data activity in each iteration using if activity and if the current file size is greater than the variable, then inside **True activities** of **if** we will set the variable to current size and store the current filename using set variable activities.
- After the ForEach, our large filename in current folder will be stored in a variable and we need to return this filename to the parent pipeline like below.
  [image]

Now, in parent pipeline, get the large file in the current folder using `@activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineReturnValue.Largefilename` expression. Use parameterized dataset(subfolder and filename are parameterized) as source of the copy activity and give the above expression for the filename.

[image]

In sink also, use parameterized dataset for filename and give same expression.

Execute the pipeline and you can see my large files from each folder were copied to the destination folder.

[image]

Go through the below JSONs for reference:

**Parent pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "parent",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Folders",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Get Metadata2",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "subfolders",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "subfolder_name": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "childItems"
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Execute Pipeline1",
                            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Metadata2",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "pipeline": {
                                    "referenceName": "Child",
                                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                                },
                                "waitOnCompletion": true,
                                "parameters": {
                                    "files_list": {
                                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata2').output.childItems",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "current_subfolder": {
                                        "value": "@item().name",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Execute Pipeline1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                        "quoteAllText": true,
                                        "fileExtension": ".txt"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "Files",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "subfolder_name": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineReturnValue.Largefilename",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "TargetCSV",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "targetfilename": {
                                            "value": "@activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineReturnValue.Largefilename",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**Child pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "Child",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.files_list",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Get Meta data for size",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "Files",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "subfolder_name": {
                                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.current_subfolder",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "size"
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "If Condition1",
                            "type": "IfCondition",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Meta data for size",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "expression": {
                                    "value": "@greater(activity('Get Meta data for size').output.size, variables('max'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "ifTrueActivities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Set the current size as Max_size",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "max",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@activity('Get Meta data for size').output.size",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Set the current file name as large file",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [
                                            {
                                                "activity": "Set the current size as Max_size",
                                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                                    "Succeeded"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "filename",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@item().name",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "max",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@int('0')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Return large file name in this folder",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "pipelineReturnValue",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "key": "Largefilename",
                            "value": {
                                "type": "Expression",
                                "content": "@variables('filename')"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "setSystemVariable": true
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "files_list": {
                "type": "array"
            },
            "current_subfolder": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "max": {
                "type": "Integer"
            },
            "filename": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**Folders Dataset JSON(Used in first Get meta data activity)**:

```
{
    "name": "Folders",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureDataLakeStorage1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
                "fileSystem": "data2"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "\\",
            "firstRowAsHeader": true,
            "quoteChar": "\""
        },
        "schema": []
    }
}
```

**Sub Folders Dataset(Used inside parent pipeline Foreach):**

```
{
    "name": "subfolders",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureDataLakeStorage1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "subfolder_name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
                "folderPath": {
                    "value": "@dataset().subfolder_name",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "fileSystem": "data2"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "\\",
            "firstRowAsHeader": true,
            "quoteChar": "\""
        },
        "schema": []
    }
}
```

**Files Dataset(Used in child pipeline Get meta data and parent pipeline copy activity):**

```
{
    "name": "Files",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureDataLakeStorage1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "subfolder_name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "filename": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
                "fileName": {
                    "value": "@dataset().filename",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "folderPath": {
                    "value": "@dataset().subfolder_name",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "fileSystem": "data2"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "\\",
            "firstRowAsHeader": true,
            "quoteChar": "\""
        },
        "schema": []
    }
}
```

**Target dataset(Used in parent pipeline copy activity sink)**:

```
{
    "name": "TargetCSV",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureDataLakeStorage1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "targetfilename": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
                "fileName": {
                    "value": "@dataset().targetfilename",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "folderPath": "FolderC",
                "fileSystem": "target"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "\\",
            "firstRowAsHeader": true,
            "quoteChar": "\""
        },
        "schema": []
    }
}
```

Comment: works like a charm. I tried the approach with the external pipeline myself but could not get it to work. This works perfectly thanks for getting me unstuck finally!